# Why Windows Service can not get files from shareed folder

Tags: java, file, shared-directory

```
import java.io.File;
public class ShareDrive {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Directory path here
    String path = "\\\\192.168.168.43\\MyShare"; 
    System.out.println("File is copied successful!");
    System.out.println(path);
    String files;
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

    for(int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++){
        if(listOfFiles[i].isFile()){
            files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            System.out.println(files);
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have code to get files from the shared folder
If I use:
javac ShareDrive.java
java ShareDrive
I worked
But when I apply it to the project, I built it to .war and use windows service to start it
Return null
Please help me for it
Thank you

Comment: What is your web server (java container)? I suggest to check it’s configurations.

Comment: @Iman
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<service>
    <id>8890-test</id>
    <name>8890-test</name>
    <description>8890-test Windows Service</description>
    <executable>java</executable>
    <arguments>-XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx2g -Xms32m -jar "8890-test.war" 100</arguments>
    <logpath>%BASE%\logs</logpath>
  <log mode="roll-by-time">
  <pattern>yyyyMMdd</pattern>
 </log>
</service>`
I use windows service to start application

Comment: Services normally run on a different user. Are you sure that user has access to the shared folder?

Comment: @dan1st I set security allowed all user but it null

Comment: Does it work if you use the program without the servie? Does adding `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net use \\\\192.168.168.43\\MyShare");` work if you add it to the start of the program?

Comment: @dan1st I try to create 1 file ShareDrive.java
I run javac ShareDrive.java java ShareDrive and it worked

Comment: But when applied to project, build to .war file and run by Windows Service it not work

Comment: In that case, go ro Event Viewer/ Windows Logs / System and check if there is an error message there that can help.

Comment: @Iman I go to log and no error

Comment: I try to test by small code and run by javac ABC.java it works but when apply to project, build to .war and run by windows service, it not work